# SharePoint Online CustomAction redirect error

Tags: custom-actions

I have a problem with the redirect in the `<CustomAction>` element where the button subscribes to

`<CommandUIHandler Command = "Redirect.Command" CommandAction = "http://www.bing.com" />`

On the redirect page I get an error like in the screenshot

[image]

There is no additional information and I have no idea what is wrong. Maybe some of you have encountered such a problem?

Comment: Which environment you are using? SharePoint online or Classic?

Comment: SharePoint online

Comment: Is it fair to presume that you are working on an Add-in, not an application extension or we part?

Comment: Yes, I'm working an Add-in